# Transformation of vector plus quaternion avoiding 4x4 matrix multiplication (using dual quaternion?)

Tags: matrices, quaternions

We have a need to translate and rotate a 3d position with orientation (expressed as quaternion) [x, y, z, qx, qy, qz, qw] by a translation and rotation expressed as vector and quaternion [x', y', z', qx', qy', qz', qw'] to give resulting position and orientation [x'', y'', z'', qx'', qy'', qz'', qw''].

At the moment we use the following steps:

- Compose [x, y, z, qx, qy, qz, qw] into affine 4x4 matrix with unit scale
- Compose [x', y', z', qx', qy', qz', qw'] into affine 4x4 matrix with unit scale
- Multiply the matrices
- Decompose resulting 4x4 matrix into [x'', y'', z'', qx'', qy'', qz'', qw'']

I am looking for a more direct approach and think this involves dual quaternions, but am not sure.

EDIT

Worked example:

Take initial position (10,10,0) with orientation (0.7071068, 0, 0, 0.7071068) (Euler PI/2, 0, 0)

If we compose these into 4x4, we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&10\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

We want to translate this (5,0,0) and rotate (-0.7071068, 0, 0, 0.7071068) (Euler -PI/2, 0, 0) so we compose this also to get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&5\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Multiplying these gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&15\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This can be decomposed into position (15,0,0) and orientation (0,0,0,1).

Obviously this is a contrived case with simple numbers but hopefully makes the requirement clearer.

Comment: No idea. There is an infinity of methods to transform vectors into each other. Please give the full details of what you do at the moment. What is a $4\times 4$ matrix with "unit scale"? Don't forget to use MathJax.

Comment: Are you interpreting a "3d vector plus quaternion" as an affine isometry of 3D space? What does it mean to "transform" one of these things by another - are you trying to find the composition of the two isometries? Or what?

Comment: Have added worked example. Does this make it clearer? Tx

Comment: So the answer to my first two questions are "yes," you're using vector-quaternion pairs to represent affine isometries and want the composition of two isometries. To rotate a vector $\bf x$ by a quaternion $p$, you conjugate it, i.e. the rotated vector is $p{\bf x}p^{-1}$ (and note $p^{-1}=\bar{p}$ if $p$ has unit norm). If you use $(p,{\bf u})$ to denote the affine isometry ${\bf x}\mapsto p{\bf x}\bar{p}+{\bf u}$, then the composition of $(p,{\bf u})$ and $(q,{\bf v})$ is $$p(q{\bf x}\bar{q}+{\bf v})\bar{p}+{\bf u} $$ which is represented by $(pq,p{\bf u}\bar{p}+{\bf v})$.

Comment: @runway44 do you have ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ reversed? That is, should it be $(pq, p{\bf v}\bar p + {\bf u})$?

Comment: @Neapolitan Yes, it should be.